# Why Event Dispatch Thread can't create new EDT?

Tags: java, swing, freeze, event-dispatch-thread

When I was creating "cnc control" program and I wanted to create file browser for loading or saving the drilling plan. So I made simple file browser and tested it [works fine], but in main class when ActionListener is used to construct new EDT, the UI/JFrame freezes and main thread keeps going.

Nowadays I know how to go around this obstacle by using variable(s) in main thread and execute the browser with them.

**in short: EDT is thread right? Why it can not create another Event Dispatch Thread like any other thread?**

**Edit:** I didn't know that there can be only one EDT per java application and freezing is caused by infinite loop inside of it. Thanks to **MadProgrammer** for clearing things up.

**sorry about that pile of text below. (My classes are difficult to separate)**

here is the example if my english is so ridiculously bad/I'm confusing you:

**Working Main class:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
//functions:
static void LoadSaveWhatever(){
    FileBrowser fb=new FileBrowser();                                   //create browser class  success!
    fb.createWindow(FileBrowser.SAVE,"c:\\",new String[]{".txt"});  //create browser...but it's never completed!?
    while(fb.Done()==false&fb.w!=null){                                 // wait 'till fb kills itself
        System.out.println("waitting for address.. PLUS still runing!");
        if(fb.w.isVisible()==false){
            break;
        }try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);             //because of spamming and less power consuming
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            // never happened but it's good to be there
        }
    }System.out.println("target: "+fb.GetTarget()); //print target file
}

static boolean saveOrLoad=false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //set things up
    JFrame w=new JFrame();                                  //main window
    JButton b=new JButton("Open (quite old/bad/laggy) browser");//the button
    boolean Alive=true;
    long t=0;               //auto close

    //EDT?
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            saveOrLoad=true;
        }
    });

    //construct
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       //making sure javaw.exe dies after w is closed
    w.setVisible(true);                                     //...
    w.getContentPane().add(b,BorderLayout.CENTER);          //put button in JFrame
    w.pack();

    //main loop
    t=System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(Alive){
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-t>(3*60*1000)){       //close program after 3 min
            Alive=false;
        }if(saveOrLoad){
            LoadSaveWhatever();
            saveOrLoad=false;
        }try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}`
```

**Freezing Main class**

```
        import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main2 {
        //functions:
            static void LoadSaveWhatever(){
                FileBrowser fb=new FileBrowser();                                   //create browser class  success!
                fb.createWindow(FileBrowser.SAVE,"c:\\",new String[]{".txt"});  //create browser...but it's never completed!?
                while(fb.Done()==false&fb.w!=null){                                 // wait 'till fb kills itself
                    System.out.println("waitting for address.. PLUS still runing!");
                    if(fb.w.isVisible()==false){
                        break;
                    }try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);             //because of spamming and less power consuming
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();            // never happened but it's good to be there
                    }
                }System.out.println("target: "+fb.GetTarget()); //print target file
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                //set things up
                JFrame w=new JFrame();                                  //main window
                JButton b=new JButton("Open (quite old/bad/laggy) browser");//the button
                boolean Alive=true;
                long t=0;               //auto close

                //EDT?
                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        LoadSaveWhatever();
                    }
                });

                //construct
                w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       //making sure javaw.exe dies after w is closed
                w.setVisible(true);                                     //...
                w.getContentPane().add(b,BorderLayout.CENTER);          //put button in JFrame
                w.pack();

                //main loop
                t=System.currentTimeMillis();
                while(Alive){
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-t>(10*1000)){     //close program after 3 min [NOT WORK!!!!! need to use kill switch]
                        Alive=false;
                    }try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

**the FileBrowser class:**

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

    import data.DataConverter;
    import file.Browser;

    public class FileBrowser{
        public volatile JFrame w;
        public Browser brow=new Browser();

        private JButton Back;
        private JButton Goto;
        private JButton Save;
        private JButton Cancel;

        private JTextField newadd;
        private JTextArea FolderInfo;
        private JTextArea FileInfo;
        private JTextField name;
        private JPanel gotoBar;
        private JPanel top;
        private JPanel mainp;
        private JPanel cenl;
        private JPanel cenr;
        private JPanel downrigth;
        private JPanel downcen;
        private JPanel downleft;
        private JPanel center;
        private JPanel down;
        private JPanel file;
        private JPanel folder;
        private JPanel filei;
        private JPanel folderi;

        private JComboBox<String> HDp;
        private JComboBox<String> Format;
        private JList<String> filep;
        private JList<String> folderp;

        private JScrollPane main;
        private JScrollPane filePane;
        private JScrollPane folderPane;

        private long lastClick=0;
        public static int BROWSER=0;
        public static int SAVE=1;
        public static int LOAD=2;

        private volatile String Target="";
    private volatile boolean TSelected=false;

    public synchronized boolean Done(){
        return TSelected;
    }
    public synchronized String GetTarget(){
        return Target;
    }



    public synchronized void updateHDs(){
        if(brow!=null&HDp!=null){
            String[] s=brow.getHardDrivesString();
            if(s!=null){
                HDp.removeAllItems();
                for(int a=0;a<s.length;a++){
                    HDp.addItem(s[a]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void updateFiles(){
        if(brow!=null&HDp!=null){
            if(filep!=null){
                String[] s=brow.getFilesString(null);
                if(s!=null){
                    filep.setListData(s);
                }else{
                    filep.setListData(new String[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void updateFolders(){
        if(brow!=null&HDp!=null){
            if(folderp!=null){
                String[] s=brow.getFoldersString(null);
                if(s!=null){
                    folderp.setListData(s);
                }else{
                    folderp.setListData(new String[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void updateTop(){
        if(newadd!=null&Goto!=null){
            if(newadd.getText()!=brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator){
                newadd.setText(brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator);
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void setFormats(String[] s){
        if(s!=null&Format!=null){
            Format.removeAllItems();
            for(int a=0;a<s.length;a++){
                Format.addItem(s[a]);
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void Update(){
        updateFolders();
        updateFiles();
        updateTop();
        w.pack();
    }
    public synchronized void Destroy(){
        if(w!=null){
            w.dispose();
            w=null;
        }TSelected=true;
    }

    public synchronized void createWindow(int windowType,String startAdd,String[] Formats){
        try{
            w.removeAll();
            w.setVisible(false);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
        }if(brow==null){
            brow=new Browser();
        }brow.setAddress(startAdd);
        w=null;w=new JFrame();w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mainp=null;
        down=null;
        HDp=null;
        filep=null;
        folderp=null;
        main=null;

        folderi=new JPanel();
        filei=new JPanel();
        mainp=new JPanel();
        top=new JPanel();
        gotoBar=new JPanel();
        down=new JPanel();
        file=new JPanel();
        folder=new JPanel();
        cenl=new JPanel();
        center=new JPanel();
        cenr=new JPanel();
        downrigth=new JPanel();
        downcen=new JPanel();
        downleft=new JPanel();

        Save=new JButton();
        Cancel=new JButton();
        Back=new JButton("Folder up");
        Goto=new JButton("Go to");


        HDp=new JComboBox<String>();
        Format=new JComboBox<String>();

        filep=new JList<String>();
        folderp=new JList<String>();



        FolderInfo=new JTextArea();
        FileInfo=new JTextArea();

        name=new JTextField();
        newadd=new JTextField();

        updateHDs();

        top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        HDp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if(brow==null){
                    brow=new Browser();
                }brow.setAddress(""+HDp.getSelectedItem());
                Update();
            }
        });
        folderp.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(FolderInfo!=null){
                    String[] s=brow.getInfoString(brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+folderp.getSelectedValue());
                    FolderInfo.setText(DataConverter.StringsToString(s));w.pack();
                }
            }
        });
        folderp.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getButton()==1){
                    if(lastClick+700>=System.currentTimeMillis()){
                        if(folderp.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
                            if(brow.type==-1){
                                brow.setAddress(folderp.getSelectedValue());
                            }else{
                                brow.setAddress(brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+folderp.getSelectedValue()+File.separator);
                            }Update();
                        }
                    }else{
                        lastClick=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(e.getButton()==3){
                        if(brow.getCurrentPath()!=null){
                            brow.FolderUp();
                            Update();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        filep.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(FileInfo!=null){
                    String[] s=brow.getInfoString(brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+filep.getSelectedValue());
                    FileInfo.setText(DataConverter.StringsToString(s));w.pack();
                }
            }
        });
        filep.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getButton()==1){
                    if(lastClick+700>=System.currentTimeMillis()){
                        if(filep.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
                            try {
                                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "+brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+filep.getSelectedValue());
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        lastClick=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(e.getButton()==3){
                        if(brow.getCurrentPath()!=null){
                            brow.FolderUp();
                            Update();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        Back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(brow.getCurrentPath()!=null){
                    brow.FolderUp();
                    Update();
                }
            }
        });
        Goto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(brow!=null){
                    File tf=new File(newadd.getText());
                    if(tf.exists()){
                        if(tf.isDirectory()){
                            brow.setAddress(newadd.getText());
                            Update();
                        }else{
                            brow.setAddress(tf.getParent());
                            Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Destroy();
            }
        });

        gotoBar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        newadd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650,20));
        gotoBar.add(newadd,BorderLayout.WEST);
        gotoBar.add(Goto,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gotoBar.add(Back,BorderLayout.EAST);
        top.add(gotoBar);

        filePane=new JScrollPane(filep);
        folderPane=new JScrollPane(folderp);

        folder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        folder.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Folders:"));
        folder.add(folderPane);
        file.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        file.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Files:"));
        file.add(filePane);

        cenl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        cenl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420,500));
        cenl.add(folder);
        cenl.add(file);

        folderi.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Folder info:"));
        filei.setBorder(new TitledBorder("File info:"));

        FolderInfo.setEditable(false);
        FileInfo.setEditable(false);

        folderi.add(new JScrollPane(FolderInfo));
        filei.add(new JScrollPane(FileInfo));

        cenr.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        cenr.add(folderi);
        cenr.add(filei);

        center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        center.add(cenl,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        center.add(cenr,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        downleft.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        downleft.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Quick"));
        downleft.add(HDp);

        downcen.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        downcen.add(name);
        downcen.add(Format);

        downrigth.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        downrigth.add(Save);
        downrigth.add(Cancel);

        down.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        down.add(downleft,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        down.add(downcen,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        down.add(downrigth,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        mainp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainp.add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainp.add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainp.add(down,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Update();
        main=new JScrollPane(mainp);

        switch(windowType){
        default:
            w.setTitle("File Browser module V2.0");
            Save.setText("[unavailable]");
            TSelected=true;
            Cancel.setText("Close");
            break;
        case 1:
            w.setTitle("Save [whatever] to..");
            Save.setText("Save");

            Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if(brow.type!=-1){
                        if(name.getText().length()>0){
                            Target=brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+name.getText()+Format.getSelectedItem();
                            TSelected=true;
                            Destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            Cancel.setText("Cancel");
            break;
        case 2:
            w.setTitle("Load [whateverLongAsIAcceptIt] from...");
            Save.setText("Open");
            Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if(brow.type!=-1){
                        if(filep.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
                            Target=brow.getCurrentPath()+File.separator+filep.getSelectedValue();
                            TSelected=true;
                            Destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            Cancel.setText("Cancel");
                break;
            }w.getContentPane().add(main);
            setFormats(Formats);
            w.pack();
            w.setVisible(true);
            w.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
        }



    }
```

**DataConverter class**

```
        public class DataConverter {
        public static int INT=1;
        public static int CHAR=2;
        public static int STRING=3;
        public static int IntList=4;
        public static int CharList=5;
        public static int StringList=6;

        public static String CharToString(char c){
            return (""+c);
        }
        public static String CharsToString(char[] c){
            String s="";
            if(c!=null){
                if(c.length>0){
                    for(int a=0;a<c.length;a++){
                        s=s+(""+c[a]);
                    }return s;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static int CharToInt(char c){
            return ((int)c);
        }
        public static int[] CharsToInts(char[] c){
            int[] i;
            if(c!=null){
                if(c.length>0){
                    i=new int[c.length];
                    for(int a=0;a<c.length;a++){
                        i[a]=((int)c[a]);
                    }return i;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static char StringToChar(String s){
            if(s!=null){
                if(s.length()>0){
                    return s.charAt(0);
                }
            }return 0;
        }
        public static char[] StringToChars(String s){
            if(s!=null){
                if(s.length()>0){
                    char[] c=new char[s.length()];
                    for(int a=0;a<c.length;a++){
                        c[a]=s.charAt(a);
                    }return c;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static int StringToInt(String s){
            if(s!=null){
                if(s.length()>0){
                    return ((int)s.charAt(0));
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public static int[] StringToInts(String s){
            if(s!=null){
                if(s.length()>0){
                    int[] i=new int[s.length()];
                    for(int a=0;a<i.length;a++){
                        i[a]=((int)s.charAt(a));
                    }return i;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static char IntToChar(int i){
            return ((char)i);
        }
        public static char[] IntsToChars(int[] i){
            if(i!=null){
                if(i.length>0){
                    char[] c=new char[i.length];
                    for(int a=0;a<i.length;a++){
                        c[a]=((char)i[a]);
                    }return c;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static String IntToString(int i){
            return ""+((char)i);
        }
        public static String IntsToString(int[] i){
            if(i!=null){
                if(i.length>0){
                    String s="";
                    for(int a=0;a<i.length;a++){
                        s=s+""+((char)i[a]);
                    }return s;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static String StringsToString(String[] s){
            if(s!=null){
                if(s.length>0){
                    String S="";
                    for(int a=0;a<s.length;a++){
                        S=S+s[a]+System.lineSeparator();
                    }return S;
                }
            }return null;
        }
        public static String[] StringToStrings(String s){
            if(s!=null){
                int a=0;
                int c=0;
                for(int b=0;b<s.length();b++){
                    if(s.substring(b,b+1).equals(System.lineSeparator())){
                        a++;
                    }
                }String[] S=new String[1+a];
                for(int b=0;b<S.length;b++){
                    if(s.substring(b,b+1).equals(System.lineSeparator())){
                        S[c]=s.substring(a,b);
                        a=b;
                    }
                }
            }return null;
        }

        public static int GetDataTypeOf(Object clip){
            try{
                if(clip.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("int[]")){
                    return DataConverter.IntList;
                }if(clip.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("char[]")){
                    return DataConverter.CharList;
                }if(clip.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("String[]")){
                    return DataConverter.StringList;
                }if(clip instanceof Integer){
                    return DataConverter.INT;
                }if(clip instanceof Character){
                    return DataConverter.CHAR;
                }if(clip instanceof String){
                    return DataConverter.STRING;
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
            }return 0;
        }

        public static Object ConvertTo(Object DataFrom,int To){
            try{
                int[] out = null;
                switch(GetDataTypeOf(DataFrom)){
                case 3:
                    out=StringToInts((String)DataFrom);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    out=(int[])DataFrom;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    out=CharsToInts((char[])DataFrom);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    out=StringToInts(StringsToString((String[])DataFrom));
                    break;
                }
                switch(To){
                case 3:
                    return IntsToString(out);
                case 4:
                    return out;
                case 5:
                    return IntsToChars(out);
                case 6:
                    return StringToStrings(IntsToString(out));
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
            }return null;
        }

        public static int[] toEigthBit(int value){
            int[] o=new int[4];
            int v=value;
            o[0]=v/(255*255*255);   //255*255*255*255
            v=v-(o[0]*255*255*255);
            o[1]=v/(255*255);       //255*255*255
            v=v-(o[1]*255*255);
            o[2]=v/(255);           //255*255
            v=v-(o[2]*255);
            o[3]=v;
            return o;
        }
        public static int fromEigthBit(int[] value){
            long o=value[3];
            o=o+value[2]*255;
            o=o+value[1]*255*255;
            o=o+value[0]*255*255*255;
            return (int)o;
        }

    }
```

**and last needed class, browser:**

```
        import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Browser {
        File f;
        File[] files;
        public int type=-1;         //-1=not exist, 0=Folder, 1=File
        String HDL="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        File[] HDs;

        public void updateHardDrives(){
            File t;
            int b=0;
            for(int a=0;a<HDL.length();a++){
                t=new File(HDL.substring(a,a+1)+":"+File.separator);
                if(t.exists()){
                    b++;
                }
            }if(b>0){
                HDs=new File[b];
                int c=0;
                for(int a=0;a<HDL.length();a++){
                    t=new File(HDL.substring(a,a+1)+":"+File.separator);
                    if(t.exists()){
                        HDs[c]=new File(HDL.substring(a,a+1)+":"+File.separator);
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public boolean updateAddress(){
            if(f!=null){
                if(f.exists()){
                    if(f.canRead()){
                        if(f.isDirectory()){
                            files=f.listFiles();
                            type=0;
                        }else{
                            files=null;
                            type=1;
                        }return true;
                    }
                }type=-1;
            }return false;
        }

        public boolean setAddress(String add){
            if(add!=null){
                f=new File(add);
                if(f.exists()){
                    if(f.isFile()){
                        type=1;
                    }else{
                        type=0;
                    }return this.updateAddress();
                }return false;
            }else{
                type=-1;
                updateHardDrives();
                files=new File[HDs.length];
                for(int a=0;a<files.length;a++){
                    files[a]=new File(HDs[a].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }return false;
        }
        public String getCurrentPath(){
            if(f!=null&type!=-1){
                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            }return null;
        }

        public String[] getInfoString(String add){
            String[] s=null;
            if(add!=null){
                File tf=new File(add);
                if(tf.exists()){
                    if(tf.isDirectory()){
                        s=new String[13];
                        s[0]=""+tf.getName();
                        s[1]="Type:\tFolder";
                        s[2]="Is readable:\t"+tf.canRead();
                        s[3]="Is writable:\t"+tf.canWrite();
                        s[4]="Is executable:\t"+tf.canExecute();
                        s[5]="Is hidden:\t"+tf.isHidden();
                        s[6]="Absolute path:\t"+tf.getAbsolutePath();
                        try {
                            s[7]="Canonical path:\t"+tf.getCanonicalPath();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            s[7]="Canonical path:\t"+"Error";
                        }s[8]="Folders size:\t"+tf.length()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[9]="Usable space:\t"+tf.getUsableSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[10]="Free space:\t"+tf.getFreeSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[11]="Total Space:\t"+tf.getTotalSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[12]="Parent address:\t"+tf.getParent();
                    }if(tf.isFile()){
                        s=new String[13];
                        s[0]=""+tf.getName();
                        s[1]="Type:\tFile";
                        s[2]="Is readable:\t"+tf.canRead();
                        s[3]="Is writable:\t"+tf.canWrite();
                        s[4]="Is executable:\t"+tf.canExecute();
                        s[5]="Is hidden:\t"+tf.isHidden();
                        s[6]="Absolute path:\t"+tf.getAbsolutePath();
                        try {
                            s[7]="Canonical path:\t"+tf.getCanonicalPath();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            s[7]="Canonical path:\t"+"Error";
                        }s[8]="Files size:\t"+tf.length()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[9]="Usable space:\t"+tf.getUsableSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[10]="Free space:\t"+tf.getFreeSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[11]="Total Space:\t"+tf.getTotalSpace()+" Byte(s)";
                        s[12]="Parent address:\t"+tf.getParent();
                    }return s;
                }
            }else{System.out.println("failed: ");
                if(f!=null){
                    if(f.exists()){

                    }
                }
            }return s;
        }
        public String[] getNamesString(String add){
            String[] s=null;
            if(add!=null){
                File tf=new File(add);
                if(tf.isDirectory()){
                    if(2<tf.list().length){
                        s=tf.list();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(f!=null){
                    if(f.isDirectory()){
                        s=f.list();
                    }
                }
            }return s;
        }
        public String[] getFilesString(String add){
            String[] s=null;
            File[] fi=null;
            if(add!=null){
                File tf=new File(add);
                if(tf.isDirectory()){
                    fi=tf.listFiles();
                    if(fi!=null){
                        int b=0;
                        for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                            if(fi[a].isFile()){
                                b++;
                            }
                        }s=new String[b];b=0;
                        for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                            if(fi[a].isFile()&b<s.length){
                                s[b]=fi[a].getName();b++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(f!=null&type!=-1){
                    if(f.isDirectory()){
                        fi=f.listFiles();
                        if(fi!=null){
                            int b=0;
                            for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                                if(fi[a].isFile()){
                                    b++;
                                }
                            }s=new String[b];b=0;
                            for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                                if(fi[a].isFile()&b<s.length){
                                    s[b]=fi[a].getName();b++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }return s;
        }
        public String[] getFoldersString(String add){
            String[] s=null;
            File[] fi=null;
            if(add!=null){
                File tf=new File(add);
                if(tf.isDirectory()){
                    fi=tf.listFiles();
                    if(fi!=null){
                        int b=0;
                        for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                            if(fi[a].isDirectory()){
                                b++;
                            }
                        }s=new String[b];b=0;
                        for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                            if(fi[a].isDirectory()&b<s.length){
                                s[b]=fi[a].getName();b++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{/*
                if(f!=null){
                    if(f.isDirectory()){
                        fi=f.listFiles();
                        if(fi!=null){
                            int b=0;
                            for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                                if(fi[a].isDirectory()){
                                    b++;
                                }
                            }s=new String[b];b=0;
                            for(int a=0;a<fi.length;a++){
                                if(fi[a].isDirectory()&b<s.length){
                                    s[b]=fi[a].getName();b++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }*/
                if(files!=null){
                    int b=0;
                    for(int a=0;a<files.length;a++){
                        if(files[a].isDirectory()){
                            b++;
                        }
                    }s=new String[b];b=0;
                    for(int a=0;a<files.length;a++){
                        if(files[a].isDirectory()){
                            if(type!=-1){
                                s[b]=files[a].getName();
                                b++;
                            }else{
                                s[b]=""+files[a];
                                b++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }return s;
        }
        public String[] getHardDrivesString(){
            String[] s=null;
            this.updateHardDrives();
            //try{
                s=new String[HDs.length];
                for(int a=0;a<HDs.length;a++){
                    s[a]=HDs[a].getAbsolutePath();
                }
            return s;
        }
        public void FolderUp(){
            String Nadd=f.getParent();
            setAddress(Nadd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is way too much. please ask a specific, answerable question. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I really don't understand your question, but for information about the `EDT` I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: @pennstatephil Perhaps you just look size of my question insted of reading couple of lines. My question is summarised in **bold** letters and the clases are just for testing (if some one is intrested to see&try what i mean). there is nothing wrong in last 3 class or first one. but I looked your link and sorry. my program's classes are sometimes difficult to separate.

Comment: @c0deK1ller Perhaps you should take closer look at these "bold" sections, as I'm still confused over what it is you're asking. Remember, the meaning of communication is the interruption of the receiver. I can see you're having issues with mutil threaded access to the EDT, blocking the EDT and failing to use a dialog instead of a frame. I would guess that Swing can do lots of "fancy" stuff, I know, because I do lots of "fancy" stuff with it all the time, but you're failing to understand the core API, what's available to you and how it works...at a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues you seem to be having is a misunderstanding of concurrency and how the Event Dispatching Thread actually works.

Swing (and almost all GUI frameworks) is a single threaded environment. That is all interactions with the UI must be done from within the context of the EDT. So any time you want to create or change the UI, it must be done from within the EDT.

All events raised by the EDT (such as the `actionPerformed`) are done so from with the context of the EDT.

The EDT basically pops an event off the event queue and processes it, notifying all interested parties that something has occurred, until all the interested parties return from this call, the EDT can not process any more events.

Like any thread, if you perform any long running or call any blocking process, nothing else can be executed until that block of code completes.

So, in your code, all your wonderful loops are actually blocking the EDT, preventing it from processing any new events and causing your application to appear blocked.

Your "working" example is actually a fluke, a side effect of the fact that you build the UI within the main thread and starting looping here, but the `actionPerformed` method is actually called from the EDT

Start by having a read through...

- [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Also, instead of using `JFrame`, you should be using a modal `JDialog`, which has its own mechanism for blocking the code execution within the EDT, without blocking the EDT itself.

Take a look at [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), you may even consider using a `JFileChooser` instead

Comment: s/pops an event of the event queue/pops an event *off* the event queue/

Comment: @MadProgrammer ...Did you just say in proper way: there is only one EDT thread per javaw.exe? Do that mean that my freezing Main is causing infinity loop inside EDT?

Comment: @c0deK1ller Yes, there is only one EDT per Java process (although I think Java 7 does something slightly different, but essentially boils down to the same thing).  In your "not working example", when you call `LoadSaveWhatever`, you create a loop which can never be exited, because your are relying on states that can only be changed from within the same thread context that your looping in/blocking...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That clears things up!! Thank you! (best answer so far :D)